# file path invlalid when using Codeigniter Upload class on hostgator server

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, filepath, remote-server

I am using codeigniter 2.1.2 upload class to upload a file to a remote server on hostgator. I got a following error when trying to upload a file.

`The upload path does not appear to be valid.`

Here is my folder structure:

my-addon-domain/

----**import**(target folder)

----application/

--------controller/

------------upload_controller.php

in my controller, I have tried set different path to $config['upload_path'] including

1. /home/my-hostgator-username/public_html/my-addon-domain-folder/import/'
2. ../import/
3. my-site-url/import/

None of these work. I am sure to set writeable permission to folder "import".

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `realpath`

```
 $config['upload_path'] = realpath('import');
```

(would suggest your import folder is one level beneath the web server root folder (where index.php resides)

or

```
 $config['upload_path'] = './import/';
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Folder "import" is under the my-addon-domain-folder, however realpath will return the the path to my controller file, in my case will be "/home/my-hostgator-username/public_html/my-addon-domain-folder/application/controllers.

Comment: @user1310312 Have you checked this: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/81679/ - Are you sure you have initialized the config... $this->upload->initialize($config);

Comment: I applied $config['upload_path'] = realpath('/home/my-hostgator-username/public_html/my-addon-domain-folder/import/') as you suggested. it works now. thank you so much for pointing it out.

Comment: and tried $this->upload->initialize($config) as well. it works as well. wired that I haven't read anything about it in the user document. Anyway you are very helpful. Thank you again. Save me a good night.